# Regex find string between string

Tags: regex

I want to find a string in 3 types of inputs :

1. Client XXX.MYDOMAIN.COM is
2. Client YYY is
3. Client ZZZ.mydomain.com is

What I want is :

1. XXX
2. YYY
3. ZZZ

Can someone help me with this.
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried already, and whats wrong with just looking for the second word?

Comment: So basically you want to match the word after `Client` ?

Comment: I want to match the word between 'Client' and 'is' . What I just found is the regex does not match if the there is dot(.) as part of the name.

Comment: Breaking apart components of a hostname is a solved problem.  There is probably existing code that has been written, tested and debugged in whatever language you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?<=Client\s)\b\w+\b
```

see demo here: http://regex101.com/r/lQ9hD0

Answer (score 1):

This matches to the 3 example strings after Client:

```
Client (XXX|YYY|ZZZ)
```

Or if you would like to match anything 3 character:

```
Client (...)
```

Comment: ...or `Client\s+(\w+)`.  The main point is, capturing groups are more widely supported than lookbehinds, and much more flexible.